# Azure mobile services vs Azure App service vs plain Web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Can anyone please point out any benefits of using Azure Mobile services vs using a plain Azure app service / clean web api? For a starter / project type for a backend mobile solution.

I have somewhat mixed feelings on why I would want to use Azure Mobile Services.

As far as I see on Azure Mobile services you have an easier way of authenticating, you can use the notifcations hub more easily
and you have the different "built-in" ways of handling data (table storage etc).

Usually you would want some custom logics, user registration and handling when users register to your backend and you would like a more solid way of handling
and storing the data not privided by the OOTB datastorage.

You might also have another preference than using the /Table/ odata-endpoint you get with it or end up doing lots of logics to make your DAO's return data in properly for the OData endpoints.

All these things; IMO makes it more difficult to make the API/backend clean when using Azure Mobile services rather than a simple Web API with OData endpoints and swagger documentet API that can be used in a mobile-app just as easy.

Implementing / handling authentication and notifications ++ in Web Api ain't that diffucult nor time consuming.

So my problem Azure Mobile services is that it tends to fine for dev / prototyping and testing, but it might get really messy really fast when developing a proper backend.

Any thoughts and reasons why one should choose one instead of the other?

Answer (score 1):

Think of Azure Mobile Services as V1 and App Service/Mobile App as V2.  While Microsoft hasn't announced that Mobile Services will be phased out in the near future, if you start a new project, you should definitively look at App Service.

Answer (score 1):

due to the fact that many people are confused about wether to take Web API or Web App or something different. They are going to put it all under one name. The underlying technology will be the same "i think".
But now you'll have in your portal the opportunity to add mobile push notifications, or add your swagger api definitions.
So when you're goint to stick with App Services you're not going to limit yourself.
Even when you're going to take Web Api you'll get all the functions as if you would take an App Service (if i'm correct).
*Edit: I looked it up in the portal. As I said, my old Web App Projects have the same settings as Web Api projects. So you don't need to decide anymore which kind of project you're taking. You get all the benefits out of the App Service.